# Linux sh script split sentence into words

Tags: linux, sh

I have a script which takes as input a sentence into `$1`.
How can I split `$1` which is for example `"a b c d e"` into `a` `b` `c` `d` `e` and access them individually ?
Using `sh` not `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `bash`, `sh` does not support arrays. If you need to access each element, you can use the default splitting functionality in say a `for` loop:

```
for w in $1; do
    echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

Note the lack of quotes around `$1`. This ensures that it gets split into words rather than being treated monolithically. Replace `echo` with whatever handling your heart desires.

If you are only interested in a specific element, you can use `cut`, which will work in any shell since it is a program, not part of `sh`:

```
echo "$1" | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Output:

```
b
```

In this case, the quotes around `$1` are optional since `echo` will dump everything regardless.

Comment: The problem with this is that I would have to loop over all of them before I can access element number X. There is no way to avoid this ?

Comment: In `sh`, no. Unfortunately it has limited functionality compared to the things bash has us taking for granted.

Comment: I guess this will have to do for `sh`. Thank you

Comment: Wait a sec. You can always use `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

A script is named as `a.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
tokens=( $1 )
echo ${tokens[*]}  # all array data
echo ${#tokens[@]} # length of array
echo ${!tokens[@]} # get all index
echo ${tokens[0]}  # first data in array
echo ${tokens[1]}  # second data in array

for index in ${!tokens[@]}; do
  echo $index : ${tokens[$index]}
done
```

Run `a.sh "a b c d e"`. You can see the result as following.

```
$ bash a.sh "a b c d e"
a b c d e
5
0 1 2 3 4
a
b
0 : a
1 : b
2 : c
3 : d
4 : e
```

Good luck!

Comment: The OP specifically asked for no bash.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use double quotes (") to prevent the shell from parsing a, b, and c into separate arguments.

```
EXAMPLE:

vi cat tmp.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo '$1=' $1 ', $@=' $@

./tmp.sh "a b c"
$1= a b c , $@= a b c

./tmp.sh a b c
$1= a , $@= a b c
```

NOTES:

The syntax '$1' prevents the shell from "expanding" the first argument, so you see "$" instead of "a"

The a b c is treated as 3 arguments ($1, $2 and $3); "a b c" is treated as one argument ($1). In this example, "a b c" (double quotes) and 'a b c' (single quotes) would be equivalent.

The "quote" syntax is the same, regardless if you're using the Bourne shell ("sh") or "bash".

If you wanted to treat an aggregate ("a b c") as separate elements, you can use the "$@" argument.

Finally, "/bin/sh" on most systems is the Posix shell, not the Bourne shell.  Hence is doesn't necessarily share the Bourne shell's limitations:

- [What is difference between #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash)
- [Arrays in Unix Bourne Shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137566/arrays-in-unix-bourne-shell)

Comment: this is a repost of your previous. It still does not answer the OP's question at all.

Answer (score 0):

a.sh

```
echo $1 | cut -d ' ' -f $2
```

run `a.sh "a b c d e" 3`.

```
c
```

Comment: What are you trying to say here ?

Comment: @alex wants to tokenise and access directly via index.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.